# Spring cloud gateway thread synchronization or asynchronous problem？

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I use spring-cloud-gateway to route http API，
the config such as :
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: provider_route
        uri: http://${projectB.host}
        predicates:
        - Path=/provider/b/*
spring-cloud-starter-gateway 2.1.1 & 2.1.0
I found a question i want to get help?
Why is `NettyRoutingFilter::filter` & `HttpClientOperations::send` the same thread id when the project first starts, after running for a while, the same API request, NettyRoutingFilter::filter & HttpClientOperations::send is not in a thread?

I played some Thread.current.id to reflect it.

Comment: There will be more than one thread handling requests so why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: I want to know why the project was synchronized at the beginning, and then asynchronous?